# Sending email Asynchronously

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to send an email from my application and it works fine but it takes more than 30 seconds for the email to be sent, and until that the whole browser is stuck.

How can i prevent this. Is there a way to send email Asynchronously ?

My email sending code is as follows (written in a service class)

```
def sendEmilService(User user) {
    mailService.sendMail {
        to  user.email
        from "mymail@gmail.com" 
        subject "Welcome  "
        body(view:"/email/emailsending",
        model: [ inss: user.name])
    }
}
```

Comment: This plugin takes all the guesswork out of how to do this: http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail it's great for a beginner, and until your requirements become more complex.

Comment: Please don't put "Beginner" on the end of every one of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
def sendSomeMail(User user) {

    mailService.sendMail {
        async true // send mail async
        to  user.email
        from "mymail@gmail.com" 
        subject "Welcome  "
        body(view:"/email/emailsending",
        model: [ inss: user.name])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the grails mail plugin documentation:

**Asynchronous**

The plugin can send mail asynchronously (the mail is sent on a different thread, and the sendMail message returns instantly, not waiting for the mail to be actually sent). In order to send asynchronously, 'async true' must be in the closure passed to the sendMail method, e.g.:

```
sendMail {
  async true
  to "john@g2one.com"
  subject "Hello John"
  html g.render(template:"myMailTemplate")
}
```